# Runnning the web components build.dart: FormatException: Could not find an option named "machine"

Tags: dart

I'm getting this error whenever I update some file and the build.dart runs:

```
build.dart --changed=web\index.html
file:/C:/Users/Fernando/dart/ACIMReader/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Could not find an option named "machine".
#0      ArgParser._validate (package:args/args.dart:349:21)
#1      ArgParser._parseLongOption (package:args/args.dart:488:16)
#2      ArgParser.parse (package:args/args.dart:313:27)
#3      _processArgs (package:web_components/component_build.dart:99:26)
#4      build (package:web_components/component_build.dart:34:26)
#5      main (file:///C:/Users/Fernando/dart/ACIMReader/build.dart:5:8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor recently started adding a `--machine` flag so that build scripts would know to output machine readable messages. web_components added support for the flag last week, have you run pub update?